# STM32 Doesnt Run After Reset

Tags: power, stm32, stm32f4, reset

I'm having the odd problem where a STM32F4 wont resume operation after pulling NRST low.
Power cycling the STM32F4 works just fine.

NRST is configured with a 0.1uF cap to ground. It has no other connections.
On removing the jumper from NRST to ground, voltage on the NRST pin is 3.3V (as it should be).

Any ideas as to what may be causing this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Check voltages on those *boot* pins (boot0, boot1). You may just run the bootloader...

Comment: How is your PDR_ON pin wired?

Answer (score 3):

Solved. It was caused by a dry joint.
Still, quite strange the way the issue presented itself.

Comment: You should mark this as the correct answer so the question shows as being answered already.